# Count records using LINQ2XML

Tags: c#, xml, razor, linq-to-xml

I need to get the count of the `inbound` transactions and the `outbound` transactions separately.  I have tried everything I know, but nothing is working.  Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<records>
    <inbound>
        <transaction>
            <customerID>0002</customerID>
            <customerName>bob</customerName>
        </transaction>
        <transaction>
            <customerID>0003</customerID>
            <customerName>harry</customerName>
        </transaction>
            .
            .
            .
        <transaction>
            <customerID>0250</customerID>
            <customerName>joe</customerName>
        </transaction>
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <transaction>
            <customerID>0002</customerID>
            <customerName>bob</customerName>
        </transaction>
        <transaction>
            <customerID>0003</customerID>
            <customerName>harry</customerName>
        </transaction>
            .
            .
            .
        <transaction>
            <customerID>0175</customerID>
            <customerName>frank</customerName>
        </transaction>
    </outbound>
</records>
```

This needs to be in C# and LINQ.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should show your tried code

Comment: how is razor related to this?

Comment: @CuongLe You're right, but my tried code is a mess right now and I'm really tired.

Comment: @MichalKlouda It's all going into a webpage.  I suppose I didn't need to flag it for Razor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to get the number of transactions for inbounds:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var c = xdoc.Descendants("inbound").Descendants("transaction").Count();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have been beating my head on this for hours.  Well, time to go kick myself for not seeing the simple way through it.